# Cordova Plugin with third-party SDK

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova, telerik, cordova-plugins

I'm trying to figure out how to create a Cordova iOS plugin with the PressReader framework. I'm an iOS developer and have no experience with Cordova, this is why I hope to find some guidance here.

This is what i have done:

1. Created a plugin
2. Added the Objective-C classes to src/iOS
3. Added the PressReader_SDK.framework to src/iOS (is this the right place ?)
4. Edited the src/www/js file
5. Edited the plugin.xml with the following in the iOS platform:

   ```
   <config-file target="config.xml" parent="/widget">
     <feature name="Hello">
       <param name="ios-package" value="HWPHello" />
     </feature>
   </config-file>

   <resource-file src="src/ios/PressReader_SDK.framework"/>

   <framework src="src/ios/PressReader_SDK.framework" custom="true" />
   <framework src="Foundation.framework"/>
   <framework src="UIKit.framework"/>

   <header-file src="src/ios/HWPHello.h" target-dir="HelloPlugin"/>
   <source-file src="src/ios/HWPHello.m" target-dir="HelloPlugin"/>
   ```

After this I've created a new Cordova app, added the plugin and then the iOS platform.

When opening the Xcode project from platforms/iOS I get the following Build error:

```
error: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS10.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/PressReader_SDK.framework: No such file or directory
```

Trying to run the app from terminal (`cordova run ios --device`) gives me the following error:

```
Error: Error code 65 for command: xcodebuild with args: -xcconfig,/Users/Andrei/desktop/hello/platforms/ios/cordova/build-debug.xcconfig,-workspace,Hello.xcworkspace,-scheme,Hello,-configuration,Debug,-destination,generic/platform=iOS,-archivePath,Hello.xcarchive,archive,CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR=/Users/Andrei/desktop/hello/platforms/ios/build/device,SHARED_PRECOMPS_DIR=/Users/Andrei/desktop/hello/platforms/ios/build/sharedpch
```

PS. the SDK does not seem to work on the simulator, and I need to test the app on a real device.

Comment: i believe you need to add the sdk in build path to make it available during compile time. Secondly add the sdk as build dependency from "build Phase " tab.

Comment: The SDK appears automatically in build phases after installing the plugin. I didn't understood completely about the build path... where exactly to add it ?

Comment: try  to add your sdk location to Build Settings -> Framework Search Paths

Comment: remove the `<resource-file src="src/ios/PressReader_SDK.framework"/>`, `<framework src="src/ios/PressReader_SDK.framework" custom="true" />`
should be enough